# Conflict in _local

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

Occasionally I am getting something along the lines of:

> http://myhosted.couchdb.com:5984/userdb-6938/_local/H73d9PBjwCczSUMy4NZ6bA%3D%3D
>   409 (Conflict)

The header response is: `{"error":"conflict","reason":"Document update conflict."}`

The request payload is:

```
{
    "_id": "_local/f.kaEuoL4i41KgUTkCHAyg==",
    "_rev": "0-10",
    "session_id": "735AF8E9-BF62-191F-9A63-760C922E1259",
    "history": [{
        "last_seq": 77,
        "session_id": "735AF8E9-BF62-191F-9A63-760C922E1259"
    },
    {
        "last_seq": 67,
        "session_id": "908B46C9-06C4-A60D-9189-CCE33ECEB252"
    },
    {
        "last_seq": 59,
        "session_id": "7B7A1737-D6AB-23F2-B3C3-954DFAC3F91A"
    },
    {
        "last_seq": 52,
        "session_id": "A7B639E5-CCEF-E1DE-91B2-8E27AB4AFB5B"
    },
    {
        "last_seq": 45,
        "session_id": "D8A322C2-5421-D493-91FB-DD85258D2194"
    }],
    "replicator": "pouchdb",
    "version": 1,
    "last_seq": 77
}
```

This is happening when performing some actions using pouchDb i.e This code will sometimes trigger it:

```
try {
  await db.bulkDocs(toBeSaved)
} catch (err) {
  errorCallback(err, importObj)
}
```

I understand [local docs](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/api/local.html) are docs that don't get replicated but **do I need to worry about the error message that shows**? The [docs](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/conflicts.html) do explain about handling conflicts but this appears to be one I can't do anything about. Also, as this is a bulk operation, which document exactly is causing the conflict?

**EDIT**

My getLocalDb call (which sorts the connection to pouch / couch):

```
getLocalDb: function (onSyncCompleteDispatch) {
    var localDb = new PouchDb(this.databaseName, {auto_compaction: true})
    var liveDb = this.getLiveDb()
    var self = this

    // Only send a db object once it has sync'd with the remote host.
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      resolve(localDb)

      // We're not using continuous sync because the loading bars on the app will go wild
      // We don't need to get data without users clicking anything at this point.
      localDb.sync(liveDb, {
        live: false,
        retry: false
      }).on('complete', function (info) {
        var requiresReload = info.pull.docs_written > 0 || info.pull.docs_read > 0 || info.push.docs_written > 0 || info.push.docs_read > 0
        if (requiresReload) {
          typeof self.onSyncCompleteCallback === 'function' && self.onSyncCompleteCallback(info)
        }
      }).on('error', function (err) {
        if (err.message === 'getCheckpoint rejected with ') {
          // Don't need to resolve anything here as we resolved it above and nothing will have
          // changed as no connection is available.
          console.log('No live connection available, return local (without sync).')
        } else {
          typeof self.onSyncErrorCallback === 'function' && self.onSyncErrorCallback(err)
          reject(err)
        }
      })
    })
  }
```

Comment: That doesn't seem a valid request payload for bulkDocs API.  buldDocs API expects an array, but you are passing an object

Comment: It's the request payload for the failing request (the one I've linked the error for). The `bulkDocs` method works fine and doesn't error.

Comment: I'm assuming pouchDB is doing something under the hood to cause this but don't know what.

Comment: You receive  409 error because the current revision of  local/f.kaEuoL4i41KgUTkCHAyg== isn't  0-10

Comment: Ok, let me clarify. This request isn't one I am making myself. This is a request pouchDB is making AFTER mine has already succeeded. I'm trying to understand where this error comes from, if it's a problem and what I can do about it. I understand why conflicts occurr and if it was my document I was updating, I'd handle it. I cannot handle this one.

Comment: It sounds like you've a continuous push replication from your pouchdb instance to the remote couchdb instance? So when you insert documents into your local database using `bulkDocs`, the error is happening when pouchdb is trying to checkpoint the replication after syncing your updates. Can you confirm whether you are replicating from pouch and whether the error is happening during replication?

Comment: @MikeRhodes Yes, I am using replication and it's happening in the background after getting the pouch DB (see my edit for the code). It could well be, I'll test my code when I can and report back (I'll disable the replication and see if it stops).